# PHP If an Hour Is Between Two Other Hours

Tags: php, datetime

I need to work out if the current hour is between two other times. For example to check if the time is between 07:00 and 10:00 I could use:

```
$currentTime = new DateTime('09:00');
$startTime = new DateTime('07:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('10:00');

if ($currentTime->format('H:i') >= $startTime->format('H:i') && $currentTime->format('H:i') <= $endTime->format('H:i')) {
    // Do something
}
```

The problem I have is what happens if the time is 01:00 and I want to check if it's between 22:00 and 07:00. I'm not bothered that that it is another day, just if it falls between those two hours on a 24hr clock. Example 01:00 is between 22:00 and 07:00

22:00, 23:00, 00:00, **01:00**, 02:00... 07:00

What I'm trying to achieve in the end is different prices can be set for a service between different times. So I currently loop through each hour working out what price bracket that hour falls into and the changing the price accordingly. If anyone has a more elegant solution for the problem I would be grateful to learn.

**UPDATE:**

Say I have a rule that says between 10pm and 7am I want to charge double. I loop through each hour from the start time to the end time and check if each hour falls between 22:00 (10pm) and 07:00 (7am) and if so it should be charged double. I want to avoid having to take in to account the date.

Comment: But, `10:00` is between `20:00` and `22:00` given `10:00` and `22:00` are scheduled the next day... In that sense, any hour lies between the two given hours. Your question is ambiguous, please be more specific...

Comment: @CommuSoft Added more information for clarity, hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use `DateTime::format()` for your comparisons. `DateTime` objects are already comparable.

To handle working with time periods that span midnight you will need to change the date so you have an accurate reflection of the actual date.

```
$currentTime = (new DateTime('01:00'))->modify('+1 day');
$startTime = new DateTime('22:00');
$endTime = (new DateTime('07:00'))->modify('+1 day');

if ($currentTime >= $startTime && $currentTime <= $endTime) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: be careful because `(new DateTime('07:00')->X_MEMBER_METHOD()` does not work in all PHP versions. Note the object Instantiation

Comment: It does in all *supported* versions. We can only go so far backwards for compatibility.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the tip about not needing format(), in the actual program currentTime was a date/time hence why it appeared with format in my example, but I see it is not needed on start and end time now. Thank you.

Comment: I understand your point clearly. Not everyone is capable of using the latest PHP build. You are just clearly being stubborn and do not receive a little bit of constructive criticism well. That is okay.

Comment: @self PHP 5.3 has reached its end-of-life; so assuming 5.4 moving forward is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Jack Okay. I never said it was unacceptable. (AT)John Conde jumped to defense when I stated a fact. It is evident that he doesn't like when people critique his answers and/or assertions.

Comment: @JohnConde - Thank you for your reply, is their anyway that you can do this without modify() as I would like users to use it for example $costs->timeBracket("22:00", "07:00", 1.5); $cost->timeBracket("07:00", "13:00", 2); So if I'm correct in reading your example modify() would not work with the second option. Thank you for those that pointed out about different versions of PHP but I am using the latest version of PHP so this should not be a problem for me but noted.

Comment: You will need to write the logic that determines when to use `DateTime::modify()`. It looks like it might be as simple as checking if the second time is earlier than the first time. If so, modify the date accordingly.

Comment: @JohnConde Many thanks adjusting the time by -1 day depending if the start time > end time worked.

Comment: Does not work for all cases.  As is the code Incorrectly returns false if $currentTime is ''23:00".  Yes, I can remove "modify('+1 day')", but if the time is variable how would you apply that and not apply that modification when required?

Answer (score 15):

```
<?php
$currentTime = strtotime('1:00');
$startTime = strtotime('22:00');
$endTime = strtotime('7:00');

if (
        (
        $startTime < $endTime &&
        $currentTime >= $startTime &&
        $currentTime <= $endTime
        ) ||
        (
        $startTime > $endTime && (
        $currentTime >= $startTime ||
        $currentTime <= $endTime
        )
        )
) {
    echo 'open';
} else {
    echo 'clse';
}
```

Comment: What about closed on weekends (Saturday and Sunday)?

Answer (score 1):

I found another way starting from the first and more popular solution that has the problem that doesn't work for me.

I have to write something between 10:00 pm and 06:00 am and the comparison does not work because when i pass midnight the endTime was always > of the start time.

so if i don't mind about the day i solved in this way:

```
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$startTime = new DateTime('22:00');
$endTime = (new DateTime('06:00'))->modify('+1 day');

if ($currentTime->format("a") == "am") { 
   // echo "It's a new day <br />"; 
   $currentTime = $currentTime->modify('+1 day');
}


if ($currentTime >= $startTime && $currentTime <= $endTime) {
    echo "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //get current DateTime
    $date = new DateTime('now');
    $currentHour = 0;
    $currentMinutes = 0;
    foreach ($date as $item=>$value ) {
        if($item=="date"){
            $p = explode(" ",$value)[1];
            $hour = explode(":",$p);
            $currentHour = $hour[0];
            $currentMinutes = $hour[1];
        }
    }
    $returnVO["success"] = ((int)$currentHour<12 || ((int)$currentHour>=22 && (int)$currentMinutes > 0) ) ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hour = (int)date('H');
echo ($hour > 7 && $hour < 22) ? 'Open' : 'Close';
```

```
$hour = (int)date('H');
echo ($hour <= 7 || $hour >= 22) ?  'Close':'Open';
```